# XX:MaxPermSize max value in 32bit

Tags: java, jvm

Can someone confirm that for a 32bit system:

Is there any disadvantage in using the below settings:

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=768m -XX:MaxPermSize=768m
```

(We need higher perm size because of excess non heap usage which is some design flaw which shall be corrected later...)

Comment: IMHO,heap usage is no way related to PermGEN space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why there would be any disadvantage, it's a simple configuration, you can do what you want.

This configuration will depend on the amount of physical memory you can use as a maximum and  how much you really need.

Also remember, it's a max size, you might never reach it.

Comment: I had even tested this configuration but just wanted a second opinion - from someone who had faced any issues in using it....

Comment: "Also remember, it's a max size, you might never reach it." - yes, but she's also setting `-XX:PermSize`.

Answer (score 1):

Profile your application to see it's behaviour and then you can get a better idea of what your min and max sizes should be.

- Use the flags: -Xloggc:gclogs.txt -XX:+PrintGCDetails -verbosegc to see generation and GC behaviour.
- Use a profiler like JConsole